# Sort, merge and unique arrays while retaining where they come from

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two arrays.

I want a div with spans containing each array item colour-coded so

- content from array1 is red,
- content from array2 is blue
- content that are in both is mauve

***Question*** how do I get quickly from unique to merged as in expected output?
I do not mind post processing the div using a diff for example as long as it is fast.

***NOTE:*** the contents of the *real* arrays will not contain any class names so solutions using the content are not what I am looking for. I am thinking some kind of comparison after a diff or hopefully more clever stuff with filter/map

[Progress so far (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/JLzrr/)

```
var red = ["01-red", "11-red", "01-in-both", "03-red", "02-in-both"];
var blue = ["10-blue","01-in-both","04-blue","02-in-both","02-blue"];
var both = red.concat(blue);

var unique = $.unique(both.slice(0)); // copy since unique destroys source
unique.sort();

$.each(unique,function(_,item) {
    $("#res").append($('<span>').html(item)).append('<br>');
});

$.each(red,function(_,item) {
    $("#res1").append($('<span class="red">').html(item)).append('<br>');
});

$.each(blue,function(_,item) {
    $("#res1").append($('<span class="blue">').html(item)).append('<br>');
});
```

Expected output would be

```
<div>
  <span class="purple">01-in-both</span><br>
  <span class="red"   >01-red</span><br>
  <span class="blue"  >02-blue</span><br>
  <span class="purple">02-in-both</span><br>
  <span class="red"   >03-red</span><br>
  <span class="blue"  >04-blue</span><br>
  <span class="blue"  >10-blue</span><br>
  <span class="red "  >11-red</span><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Since your arrays do not contain the actual class names you can do the following.

```
//create a new array of objects which contain the assigned class name for the items
var redObject = $.map(red, function(v) { return { class:blue.indexOf(v)>=0?'purple':'red', value: v };});
var blueObject = $.map(blue, function(v) { return { class:red.indexOf(v)>=0?'purple':'blue', value: v };});
var both = redObject.concat(blueObject);
//sort array on value
both.sort(function(o1,o2) {
    return o1.value == o2.value ? 0 : (o1.value > o2.value) ? 1 : -1;
});

//remove duplicatesd values.
for(var i = both.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    if(both[i].value == both[i-1].value) {
        both.splice(i,1);
    }
}
//print the value and add the class.
$.each(both,function(_,item) {
   $("#res").append($('<span>').addClass(item.class).html(item.value)).append('<br>');
});
```

Here is the resulting [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ftj/1/).

Comment: Uh oh - thanks for the attempt, but the item content cannot be used as class names. Please see update. The real arrays of course does not have anything useful for the colour coding. My unique plus sort already does what you suggest with your splices. Please try again

Comment: From what I can see on my phone yes, but can't we assign purple in one of the maps?

Comment: You can do the following, but I don't see any advantage of doing so. http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ftj/3/

Comment: Why not? Saves the loop at the end completely: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gpFb8/ - post it and I will accept

Comment: Well if you are removing duplicates you still have to loop through the `both` array one way or another. Less code isn't always better, calling indexOf for each instance on the map is slower than if we were to assign the class when we are looping and removing the duplicates from `both`.

Comment: Your currently posted code has `//remove duplicates and set class name of the duplicated values.` but it is not actually adding the class. I like the last fiddle you made and will use it

Comment: Oops. Try with var red = ["01-red", "11-red", "01-purple", "03-red", "02-purple","01-red", "11-red", "01-purple", "03-red", "02-purple"];
var blue = ["10-blue","01-purple","04-blue","02-purple","02-blue"];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39090/discussion-between-danny-and-mplungjan)

Comment: I accept the answer, I do not yet expect duplicates in the same array